# Change input and range slider dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, input, slider, typeerror

I have a slider and input field which will be added to a product via `ng-template`.
I want each slider and input field to store their individual values based on the `item.id`.
I'm either getting `Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:`
or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

The item will be loaded/shown from another component and the code above is inside that tag/the ng-template.

```
public quantities: { [articleId: string]: number } = {};
```

```
<div class="col-4">
    <mat-slider
        class="width-90-percent"
        [max]="max"
        [min]="min"
        [step]="step"
        [thumbLabel]="true"
        formControlName="quantity"
        [(ngModel)]="quantities[item.id]"
        (change)="quantities[item.id] = $event.value"
    ></mat-slider>
</div>
<div class="col-auto padding-0 margin-left-10">
    <input
        matInput
        type="number"
        class="form-control width-50-percent"
        formControlName="quantity"
        [(ngModel)]="quantities[item.id]"
    />
</div>
```

The `item` contains `quantity`.

If I set the input event no matter if with `quantities` or `quantity` it always moves both sliders and changes both values.

[image]

I want each slider and input field to have individual values based on the input/slider event.
The problem occurs when I declare the `[(ngModel)]` in the `input`.

Comment: `formControlName="quantity"` on both of controls makes them synchronized

Comment: I want them snychronized for the same `item.id`. This snipped will be shown on every `item`. But if I change the value of one, all will be changed. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: could you also provide all the elements with [formGroup] and formGroupName on them ? also formArray and formArrayName would be usefull

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot and further information.

Comment: still missing markup elements with form*** on them